# Using ffmpeg and concat demuxer producing weird video navigation behaviour

Tags: bash, audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion

When combining multiple videos segments, each encoded with H265 and Vorbis and containing the same number of streams and frame rate, I use:

```
ffmpeg  -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy output.mkv
```

Where my_list.txt is a file containing:

```
file split/split_00.mkv
file split/split_01.mkv
...
file split/split_n.mkv
```

On a first glance, the concatenation seems to be working fine. However, when I'm playing the video and I click on an arbitrary time point on the progress bar (e.g. I want to watch minute 12:00), sometimes the audio gets muted. When this happens, clicking on a time point some seconds before the "buggy" one (e.g. 11:45) and waiting until the video gets back to the "buggy" point is enough for the audio to be played correctly.

Re-encoding seems to fix the issue and allow me to go to whichever time point I want with no issue. I'd like to know if there is a way to do that directly from the concatenation step, without needing to re-encode the whole video.